# Basic script for sending email using cpanel localhost as phpmailer not working

Tags: email, smtp, localhost, cpanel

Has anyone got a basic script to allow me to fire an email to myself so I know when somebody has submitted a form?

I have installed Phpmailer but not connecting to to the server.
I use 123-reg who are unable to explain why.

The error I am getting:
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.prod.sxb1.secureserver.net' did not match expected CN=`localhost'

I am looking for using smtp as php not landing when being sent from the server.

I am told settings need to be:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "none";
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->mailer = "smtp"`;
```

Comment: What email do you want to sent your email from?